# How do I build an efficient underground farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I prefer spending most of time in Minecraft hidden underground. I would like to build an underground wheat farm that fits the following criteria:

- Can be built entirely in a hollowed-out, underground room
- All of the crops have enough light and water that they can grow as fast as possible
- It is impossible -- or at least excessively difficult -- to accidentally destroy part of it (eg. knocking down torches)
- Mobs cannot spawn anywhere in it
- It is possible to continuously walk through it, holding down one of the mouse buttons and quickly chop down all of the crops and replant them (not at the same time, of course)
- *Bonus points if there is any sort of mechanical means of collecting the wheat!*

How would I build an underground farm that met this criteria?

Comment: See http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Wheat_Farming#Tips_for_efficient.2Fautomated_farming for growing wheat the fastest.  See http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Farmland#Effective_technique for growing wheat most space efficient.  The two requirements are in conflict a tiny bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the following underground farm.  It's not optimal in terms of space, but for a farm, it's very efficient, and has automatic harvesting.  Planting is always manual on these things unfortunately, and that's the bottleneck for massive production.

```
TOP VIEW

SSSSSSS
DDDDDDD
DDDDDDD
DDDDDDD
DDDDDDD
SXSSSSX
```

I replicate the above pattern, one level up to the right for as long as you want.  `S` is stone.  `D` is tilled dirt.  The trick is with the `X` blocks.  They are water blocks at the level of the dirt blocks covered with Stone.

```
LEFT VIEW

S    S
SDDDDW
```

When you view this from the left, you see there's a channel for water to flow out of your monitor.  That is what permits automatic harvesting.  The water blocks are necessary for hydrating the soil.

On the far right, I place a water gate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If what i've heard is true - you have a flawed design. Crops grow slower if all 8 surrouding blocks are crops as well. Building in rows is a lil smarter (once again, if that statement is true)

Comment: it is. Crops grow faster in rows, or at least where the surrounding 8 blocks aren't the same crop.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 3 level underground farm, i'll post picks of it later on tonight, its about 7x24 and 4 tall for the first 2 levels and the 3rd level is my cocoa tree semi auto farm the first 2 levels are copies of one another in layout,
The layout is as follows

> 7 wide by 24 long grid
>
> WddsddW
>
> WddsddW
>
> WddsddW
>
> WddsddW
>
> WddsddW

And just continue that till its 24 blocks long
W is water
D is dirt
S is stone
Place torches along the wall at your discretion.
The cocoa farm is too complicated to describe on here, but youtube is a good place to look up ideas. Ill take pics and make a video of it shortly if you like the layout

Answer (score 1):

Not mechanized but very efficient both in means of space, effort building, effort harvesting and planting.

Water must be at most 4 blocks away (Manhattan taxi metrics), and more doesn't improve growth. Light improves growth, and placed above won't take room occupied by wheat. This much light will keep monsters from spawning too.

The basic unit of your farm is going to be a 9x9 square. There is one-block hole filled with water in the middle.

```
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ....~...
 ........
 ........
 ........
 ........
```

Then, above the soil place glowstone. You might put a solid layer of it, but a pattern of 1 every 4 blocks reduces the efficiency only marginally.

```
 ...G...G
 .G...G..
 ...G...G
 .G...G..
 ...G~..G
 .G...G..
 ...G...G
 .G...G..
 ...G...G
```

Crossection would be like this:

```
#-stone G-glowstone |-wheat =-farmland ~-water

#########
G G G G G

|||||||||
====~====
#########
```

Repeat that 9x9 pattern in line, as many times as needed. Instead of just running ahead, "reaper motions" (turning around while holding the button) harvest up to 4 lines away at a time, so harvest is fast enough that you really don't need automation. And digging is just 9x9x4 or even x3 if floor is soil.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Minecraft but the way 
I set up to carve a huge square basin
of solid block then x number of rows
(Whatever you determine sufficient),
of raw wood block also lining the 
perimeter (so the basin looks like a
barred window, then cap each wood 
block with soil.  Every other row is now
two block depth.  Then fill every ditch
between with water. I get full growth/
maturity of all blocks within a game day.
I have melons, wheat, cane, etc. which I
separate (for efficient reaping).  I have
every block on all surrounding walls 
torchlit.  Incidentally in a side room with 
almost no light I have a mushroom garden.
With the whole floor woodblock/dirtblock
stacks with a four block water pond at each
end of the room, they multiply nicely.
I'm now into growing forests underground.
(Who doesn't want giant trees that stack 
from bedrock to overworld?) Wood and
food are now endless for me underground.